# SAS: How to get the union of a different number of datasets?

Tags: sql, sas, union

I'm running code, almost in an automatic way. I just need to replace one value, and run. But there's one part where I have to do it 'by hand'.

It's the following code:

```
PROC SQL; 
   CREATE TABLE DDATA.SUS_151_ALL AS 
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM DDATA.RFN_ID673 
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID472 
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID553);
 QUIT;
```

In this case, the clients I want to get the union are here:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
   SELECT EN FROM DDATA.E5P_151; 
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DDATA.E5P_151;
QUIT;
```

Here, I obtain the following results:

```
673
472
553 
---page break--
3
```

So, I want something that automatically would read the 3 datasets I wanted to get the union and create the table `DDATA.SUS_151_ALL`.

I have other clients where I have 8 id's to join, and having to do it by hand 100 times takes me some time. I would want just to replace the 151, the source.

For example, for the other client, let's say `id=1000` like this one:

```
3
7
9
12
16
77
991
1028
```

I would want a program that would run this:

```
PROC SQL; 
   CREATE TABLE DDATA.SUS_1000_ALL AS 
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM DDATA.RFN_ID3
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID7 
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID9
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID12
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID16
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID77
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID991
                   UNION
                  SELECT * FROM DDATA.RPFN_ID1028);
QUIT;
```

Is this possible? Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Are you interested only in (sas) SQL code?

Comment: yes, something that would read the number of datasets to join and then automatically running the union

Comment: this is clear, but should it be only in SQL or could it  be in any other sas code?

Comment: i'm using SAS EG to do this work. if it works in SAS EG it's ok.

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this in SAS.  Kay's answer below is a good example of one.  Search StackOverflow for looping over a data set and you will find plenty of other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of macro to build sql code and then execute it in proc sql. Below is the code. Hope it is helpful.

```
proc sql;
    select EN into :value1 - :value&SysMaxLong from DDATA.E5P_151;
    select count(*) into :cnt from DDATA.E5P_151;
quit;

%global newtext;
%let newtext=;

%macro sqlstmt;

    %do i = 1 %to &cnt;

        %if(&i=&cnt) %then %do;
            %let newtext=&newtext. select * from DDATA.RFN_ID&&value&i ;
        %end;
        %else %do;
            %let newtext=&newtext. select * from DDATA.RFN_ID&&value&i union;
        %end;

        %put newtext=&newtext;
    %end;

%mend sqlstmt;

%sqlstmt
```

Now add this new macro variable &newtext in the proc sql statement and execute it.

```
proc sql;
    create table NEW as (&newtext);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use SQL to concatenate datasets like that. Just use a data step.

```
data all ;
  set rpfn_id: ;
run;
```

If you only want some of them say 3,7 and 9 then you could use some macro code to generate the list of dataset names.

```
%let list=3 7 9;
%let dslist=rpfn_id%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(compbl(&list)),%str( ),%str( rpfn_id)));
data all ;
  set %unquote(&dslist);
run;
```